# How to append new value in index of the null value in NSArray in swift

Tags: arrays, swift3

I wrote an API which returns the username and amount and at what time the transaction was placed. I got the response from the backend as an array of objects and I stored it as NSArray in client side. And I want to attach that response to labels so I converted that NSArray into String and In Database some fields are empty so the response returns the null values whenever the response returns the null values I am getting this error like "Could not cast the value of NSNUll to NSString".  What I thought is replace the null value in that array with string. I tried so much but it always shows the same error how to resolve that problem. This is my code :

```
                    let response = JSON as! NSDictionary
                    //example if there is an id
                    let deyaPaybalance = response.object(forKey: "Details") 
                    print(deyaPaybalance!)

                    let Amount1:[Double] = (response.object(forKey: "Amount")) as! [Double]
                    print("Amount is",Amount1)
                    for ele:Double in Amount1 {
                        self.amo += [String(ele)]

                    }
                    print("amount is in string",self.amo)
                    let time = response.object(forKey: "Time") as! NSArray
                    print("time is", time)
                    let id = response.object(forKey: "TransactionID")
                    print("id is",id!)
                    let name:NSArray = response.object(forKey: "RName") as!NSArray
                    print("name is",name)
                   // let len = name.count

                    for (object) in name.enumerated() {
                        if let i = name.index(of: "null") {
                            print("hey it's nnull")

                            //name.index(of: "null")

                        }
                        else {
                            print("hello")
                        }
                    }
                    print("name",name)
                    // It is used to get the date from the time tsamp
                    for element in time {
                        let ele = element
                        let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
                        //print("date is",date1!)
                        formatter.formatOptions = [.withFullDate,
                                                   .withTime,
                                                   .withDashSeparatorInDate,
                                                   .withColonSeparatorInTime]
                        self.date2 = formatter.date(from: ele as! String)!
                        self.anotherFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd yyyy, h:mm a" // It is used to to show the date in th form of month year and time
                        self.anotherFormatter.string(from: self.date2)
                        let b = self.anotherFormatter.string(from: self.date2)
                        let final = b.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: " ")
                        let trimmedString = final.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
                        self.dt += [trimmedString] // it is stored the final date and time
                        print("final tim is",trimmedString)


                    }
                    // End of the for loop
                    print(self.dt)

                    let contactViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TransactionDetails")as! TransactionDetails
                    contactViewController.method = deyaPaybalance as! [String]
                    contactViewController.amount = self.amo
                    contactViewController.timestamp = self.dt
                    contactViewController.transactionid = id as! [String]
                    contactViewController.name = name as! [String]// I am getting error here.
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(contactViewController, animated: true)
                    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
                    UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
```

Comment: where are you cast the value of NSNUll to NSString".??

Comment: contactViewController.name = name as! [String] . Here i am gettting the error. Because some of values in name array is null .

Answer (score 0):

You need to use like this to handle `null` in swift.

```
if let arr_name = name as? [String]{
    contactViewController.name = arr_name
}else{
    contactViewController.name = []
}
```

For replacing `nil` value in `[String]`

```
var name = ["a",nil,"3"]

if let nil_index = name.index(of: nil){
    name[nil_index] = "empty"
}    
print(name as! [String]) // Output is ["a", "empty", "3"]
```

Comment: I want to pass the remaining names to another controller even null values still exist not an empty array. so I want to change the index of null value with something.

Comment: @vijju For that you need to loop the [String] and replace null with " " or ask your service provider gives the response like this from the server side.

Comment: I wrote it like this  if let a = name.index(of: "null") {
                        name[a] = "empty"
                    } but I am getting error like this Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Int'